# Ordenar lista de posiciones respecto a la distancia desde la más cercana a la lejana

Tags: android, arraylist, ordenamiento

Estoy intentando ordenar de más cercana a mas lejana con android

```
class direccion(){
    String direccion;
    double lat;
    double long;
}
```

Intento ordenar esas direcciones a para saber cuales estan mas cerca de mi ubicacion.

Con Location se que existe un metodo que es Location.distanceTo
que de dos Location te da la distancia en metros
pero como puedo ordenar teniendo una clase que no tiene Location, o como puedo obtener Location a partir de Lat y long

Comment: Si no me equivoco, crea una variable `Location` y luego puedes usar los métodos `setLatitude` y `setLongitude`

Comment: si pero en la clase direcciones tengo latitud y long, quiero saber la forma de ordenar desde los datos que tengo, si esque se puede. como a partid de la lat y long que si tengo poder obtener un location.

Comment: Yo te sugeriría añadir una nueva propiedad a tu clase que fuera distancia. Asi con Location podrías añadir la distancia para cada punto, y despues ordenar por ese campo es trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase `Location` se construye a través de un Objeto `Point` en el constructor, para ello tendrás que utilizar tu `longitud` (o eje de coordenadas x) y tu `latitud` (eje de coordenadas y), más o menos de la siguiente manera:

```
Point myPoint = new Point(long, lat);
Location myLocation = new Location(myPoint);
```

A partir de tu nuevo location también puedes obtener la distancia al punto con el método `distanceTo` que mencionas en tu pregunta.

Si lo que necesitas finalmente es implementar un método manual de distancia entre dos puntos en la superficie terrestre, checkea información sobre la **Fórmula del Haversine**.